# Detect end of the ongoing notification ringtone

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

does anyone knows how to detect the end of an ongoing notification ringtone?
I have created a notification whereby the sound will be set to max **but** I want to revert the volume to the original volume after the notification ringtone has ended. I have tried using a timer but it is not effective if there are multiple notifications coming in.

The following is my current progress:

```
//get the default phone notification volume before it is set to maximum
phoneVolume = am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);

//set the phone notification volume to maximum
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 
am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION), 0);

//initiate the notification 
NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).notify(notificationId, notification);

//Set the phone notification volume back to default volume after 5 seconds
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
       public void run() {                
           Log.i(TAG, "Phone notification volume is set back to original volume after 5 seconds");
           am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, phoneVolume, 0);
       }
}, 5000);
```

appreciates the advices

Comment: You really shouldn't be overriding the user's volume settings in the first place. They had it set to that level on purpose.

Comment: @ianhanniballake, Hi I needed to set the volume to max to show that the notification is urgent

Comment: No, that's not how you set an urgent notification on Android. What kind of notification are you posting?

Comment: I am trying to create an app that will alert user if there is message that has high priority (Example of message with high priority: _Your dad has passed out, you need to be home now!_, or _your wife is gonna deliver soon, please come to the hospital now!_). So one of the requirement is that the notification ringtone is to be set at the maximum volume to alert the user of these high priority messages.